# Is "sailed into" used as metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

I am using this "glance" app. Every day some special wallpaper shows up on my homescreen. I bumped into this line:

> On this day: Titanic **sailed into** cinemas.

Is "sailed into" used as metaphor?

Comment: Going along with the pun pointed out in the answer by Astralbee- another pun exists here:  "_I bumped into this line_" similarly to how I and many others bumped into this HNQ.

Answer (score 17):

Yes - 'sailed in' is often used metaphorically, although in this specific example, it is probably as much of a *pun* as it is a metaphor.

"Sailed in" is sometimes used to describe an arrival or entrance which is *grand* or *smooth*, the way a large ship might glide accross the water into port. There might be some other ship-like qualities that may be brought to mind by using this metaphor.

Of course, as 'Titanic' is a movie about a ship, using this particular metaphor to talk about its arrival in cinemas is taking advantage of the seafaring imagery as a pun.

Comment: Extra layer of pun in that _Titanic_ failed to actually sail _into_ anywhere.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Irony, even.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- to be pedantic she did several days of sea tests as is common for all large ships and sailed into both Belfast and Southampton before her fateful voyage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic#Sea_trials

Comment: @MD-Tech Thank you! I was about to say that. :D Forgive us for our pedantic natures, chrylis.

Comment: @John that's what I'm here for!

Comment: I wonder whether it's possible to say conclusively that something /isn't/ a metaphor? After all, it's not identified by particular phraseology, but only by the fact that the reader can recognise the allusion.

Comment: It's kind of a double metaphor, because the Titanic of course did not have sails.  But we still use that word by convention for ships powered by other means.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- She sailed into the iceberg

Comment: @DarrelHoffman in fact the only ships which are described as "motoring" are those which have sails, but are not using them and are being propelled by an engine instead.